# Windows 8 - options how to save ListBox items so that when I close and open the app again the items are still there?

Tags: windows-8, listbox, storage

Let's say I have a ListBox:

```
ListBox myListBox = new ListBox();
myListBox.Items.Add("One");
myListBox.Items.Add("Two");
myListBox.Items.Add("Three");
```

I need to save these items somewhere in the project so that the only way getting rid of it is to uninstall the app, is it possible?

Comment: You can save the items in the application local folder, and then load them at startup/resume.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the items added as you have shown, you would have to first iterate the listbox to get the items in order to persist them.  A better option is to have the items stored in an array/object/whatever elsewhere and use that array/object/whatever to both persist the list and to populate the listview.

Then, hook into the application Suspend event.  In the event, you can persist the array/object/whatever to local storage or to the cloud, depending on what you want.  You would then check on app resume/startup if persisted data was available and restore it if it is.

Some useful links:
[Application.Suspending event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.suspending.aspx)

[Guidelines for app suspend and resume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465088.aspx)

[Part 2: Manage app lifecycle and state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh986968.aspx)